# COMException: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)) in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, camera, .net-framework-version

I attempt to implement Dino-Lite (a usb microscope) SDK into a C# WPF application (4.8 NetFramework project). I have added AxDNVideoXLib.dll and DNVideoXLib.dll (part of the SDK, they seem are designed as COM object) as COM reference in my project. Below is my source code:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using DNVideoXLib;

namespace DinoLite
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private DNVideoXClass v = new DNVideoXClass();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < v.GetVideoDeviceCount(); i++)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(v.GetVideoDeviceName(i));
            }
        }
     }
}
```

I have this exception when I run the source code:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
  HResult=0x80131501
  Message='The invocation of the constructor on type 'DinoLite.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '6' and line position '9'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(string, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, object, int[], ref System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.MessageData)
    DinoLite.MainWindow.MainWindow() in MainWindow.xaml.cs

Inner Exception 1:
COMException: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
```

I have registered DNVideoX.ocx. I have also run it in 'Release' and 'Debug' mode, both return me the same error. Any suggestions? Thank you